# Android: Huge difference in memory consumption when using drawable vs drawable-nodpi folders

Tags: java, android, drawable, dpi

I have basic Android application created with Android Studio with single image loaded in `ImageView` like this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.g01);
```

Image size is `1280x853 pix`, nothing huge. When I store the image in `drawable` folder runtime memory consumed by app is 24.35 MB vs 11.85 MB when image is stored in `drawable-nodpi` folder. Tested on `xhdpi` device with resolution of `1280x720 pix`.

In my real life app, difference is even greater 75 MB vs 25 MB.

Why the difference? I thought that `drawable` and `drawable-nodpi` folders are basically the same and serve the same purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why the difference? I thought that drawable and drawable-nodpi folders
>   are basically the same and serve the same purpose?

No they are not. `drawable` scales its content per the device's density, `drawable-nodpi` doesn't. In the first case you will get a bitmap density time width/height the original one

Comment: More specifically, `drawable` is synonymous with `drawable-mdpi`, for backwards compatibility with ancient versions of Android, before we had these density qualifiers.